# How Here counts requests when using their map control?

Tags: here-api

In the documentation, it is mentioned this: "Map, satellite and traffic tiles, for which a transaction equals 15 requests", but what counts as a request when showing their map on an Android app?

Each user section? Each time he pans/zooms/moves the map?

I've created a sample code based on their routing example, but the Usage Stats on Developer dashboard doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Starter SDK, then you will pay for requests. For Premium SDK pricing is different. To get details about pricing for Premium SDK go to https://developer.here.com/contact-us

Comment: What is considered a request? Every move of the map (pan, zoom, etc.)?

Comment: For Starter SDK it's the same as for API. You can find details here: https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-subscription. With Premium SDK you don't pay for requests, the pricing model is different, to get info about the price of Premium SDK you need to contact company representatives.