# For the here starter business plan, what constitutes a transaction?

Tags: here-api

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308709/how-here-counts-requests-when-using-their-map-control) but didnt seem to be actually answered.  I am looking into mapping options for a project, and am thinking about the business starter plan listed on [this page](https://developer.here.com/plans).

The usage details indicate that for loading a map, 15 "tiles" is considered one transaction.  First, what is a "tile"?  Second (and most importantly), what happens if the user zooms in, or pans the map?  Are more tiles then loaded?  For my use-case, approximately 300-400 map loads per day would be used, however those maps would be interacted with (zoomed in to see details, zoomed out to see location of nearby jobs, etc..).  If each of those map loads might incur a bunch more transactions, suddenly the 150k transactions/month might be too little.  Thoughts?

Comment: Wondering why the downvotes?  As far as I can see, these sorts of questions are routed to stackexchange from the developer.here.com site (and pouring over the documentation, there are no notes at all regarding this issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First, what is a "tile"?
```

One picture with rendered map data loaded by request. Typical screen what user will see will consist of several tiles. Something around exactly 15 tiles, but it depends on tile size, resolution and so on.

```
Second (and most importantly), what happens if the user zooms in, or pans the map?
```

They will be loaded again for new locations, new zoom level etc.

Comment: And just to make it crystal clear- those newly loaded tiles would then count as a transaction for each bundle of 15 tiles?

Comment: Yes, it will count as a new transaction.